# Unzip objects collection into arrays of its properties

Tags: c#, linq

Let's assume that there is some class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string A;
    public int B;
    public double C;
}
```

and we have a collection of it:

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>() 
{ 
    new SomeClass() { A = "A", B = 2, C = 4.0 }, 
    new SomeClass() { A = "B", B = 6, C = 8.0 } 
};
```

How can we write in the most efficient way the transform of this collection into three arrays (or list of arrays) of values of `A`, `B` and `C` respectively? In this case it would be:

```
var Ar = new[] { "A", "B" };
var Br = new[] { 2, 6 };
var Cr = new[] { 4.0, 8.0 };
```

So far I have **working** LINQ query:

```
var lists = list.SelectMany(c => new object[] { c.A, c.B, c.C })
                .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Object = v})
                .GroupBy(g => g.Index % 3, g => g.Object, (k,v) => v.ToArray())
                .ToList();
```

but I wonder if I'm not missing something obvious and if there is possibility to do it clever, for example without the need for creating temporary subcollections within `SelectMany`.

***Edit:*** my question is rather from theoretical point of view - if it can be done in single LINQ query (for example as a part of another, more complex single query).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you do this the simplest possible way? I think that 3 separated queries should be more efficient then `SelectMany`+`GroupBy` solution:

```
var Ar = list.Select(x => x.A).ToList();
var Br = list.Select(x => x.B).ToList();
var Cr = list.Select(x => x.C).ToList();
```

It requires only 3 iterations over `list` collection. With `GroupBy` you have only one iteration but the source collection is 3 times longer then `list`, so there is no difference (because of `SelectMany`) with additional `GetHashCode` calls to make the grouping.

**Update**

Single line version of the same approach:

```
var items = new [] {
    list.Select(x => x.A).ToList(),
    list.Select(x => x.B).ToList(),
    list.Select(x => x.C).ToList()
}
```

**Update 2**

If you don't want to use `SelectMany`, you can use `Concat` instead. However, it would require change in `GroupBy` as well:

```
var lists = list.Select(c => c.A)
                .Concat(list.Select(c => c.B))
                .Concat(list.Select(c => c.C))
                .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Object = v})
                .GroupBy(g => g.Index / list.Count, g => g.Object, (k,v) => v.ToArray())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: That's true, it is more efficient and cleaner also. I've forgot to mention that my question was rather from theoretical point of view - if it can be done in single query (for example as a part of other, more complex single query).